# A python Path.rglob pattern to match all package.json files in a directory that are not nested inside of a node_modules folder

Tags: python, glob, pathlib

I'm working with a massive monorepo, and I'm trying to write a script that will need to grab some information from all of the monorepo's package.json files, but *not* and package.json files that are nested in any of the `node_modules` folder. I've tried everything apart from just filtering them with a regex after recursively going through the entire directory, including the `node_modules` folder. I'm aware that that's an option, but ideally I'd like to be able to filter those directories before the search for performance reasons. The monorepo structure looks something like:

```
root/
    node_modules/
    apps/
        someApp/
            node_modules/
        someApp2/
            node_modules/
    packages/
        somePackage1/
            node_modules/
        somePackage2/
            node_modules/
        somePackage3/
            node_modules/
        ...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your question about this?

Comment: I don't think `rglob()` has any way to specify exceptions. You'll need to filter them out in your code that loops over the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go through the whole file tree and skip everything that is `node_modules`.

This will be much more perfomant then searching for all `package.json` and filtering them by their path.

```py
from os import walk

w = walk("/path/to/your/repo")
for(dir_path, dir_names, file_names) in w:
  if dir_path.endswith('node_modules'):
    continue
  for file in file_names:
    if file == 'package.json':
        yield os.path.join(dir_path, file)
```

Comment: Thanks!. It worked great, but for anyone coming across this in the future you'll have to swap the `endswith` method for the `__contains__` method since walk will still recursively go into the `node_modules` folder. Obviously this adds some limitations, but for my use case that worked perfectly. The obvious solution, although more work, is to walk the directory manually and just not go into the node_modules folder, but this works great for this use case.